# Foursquare - Test push fails with "Your Server returned: 502 Bad Gateway"

Tags: foursquare

I am new to Foursquare API. I am trying to get a push notification using foursquare real-time push API for Checkins at venues managed by your users.

I have created an app on Foursquare. Test push from this app fails with error : "Your Server returned: 502 Bad Gateway"

I have configured a https server on default port 443 and I could connect to the push url from browser.

How can I debug this issue? Any help would be appreciated.